# How to get the text from a child tag onChange on the parent tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to get the text (the city name) of the option tag that is inside the Select component and use it on the handleChangeCity() function. The problem is,  I've tried accessing this text in the handleChangeCity() function with event.target.text but it returns the whole option tag, not just the text inside it. How do I do this?

```
                  <Select
                      native
                      onChange={this.handleChangeCity}
                      value={location.id}
                      required
                      disabled={locacation.idState === 0}
                      style={styles.widthInput}
                    >
                      {cities.map(city=> (
                        <option key={city.id} value={city.id} disabled={city.id === 0}>
                          {city.name}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </Select>
```

The function:

```
handleChangeCity = (optionSelected) => {
    const { location } = this.state;
    this.setState({ location: { ...location, idCity: optionSelected.target.value, nameCity: optionSelected.target.text } });
  }
```

Comment: I know it's blasphemous to suggest not writing something yourself on this site, but you might want to check out the React-Select library. It's very full featured and easily shows you how to do what you want in its documentation

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you! But are you sure it shows an example like mine? I can't lose a lot of time right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the text of your `select`. To get the text of the *selected option* you can do this:

```
handleChangeCity = (optionSelected) => {
    const { location } = this.state;
    const { options, selectedIndex } = optionSelected.target;
    this.setState({
        location: {
            ...location,
            idCity: optionSelected.target.value,
            nameCity: options[selectedIndex].text
        }
    });
};
```